# How to test ruby module methods with block using Rspec?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I want to test a following method, which calls a module method with a block.

```
def test_target
  MyModule.send do |payload|
    payload.my_text = "payload text"
  end
end
```

`MyModule`'s structure is like following.

```
module MyModule
  class Payload
    attr_accessor :my_text

    def send
      # do things with my_text
    end
  end

  class << self
    def send
      payload = Payload.new
      yield payload
      payload.send
    end
  end
```

How can I test whether `MyModule` receives `send` method with a block, which assigns `"payload text"` to `payload.my_text`?

Currently I'm only testing `expect(MyModule).to receive(:send).once`. I looked through and tried [Rspec yield matchers](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-8/docs/built-in-matchers/yield-matchers) but cannot get things done. (Maybe I've ben searching for wrong keywords..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to insert a double as the `yield` argument, which you can make an assertion on.

```
payload = Payload.new
allow(Payload).to receive(:new).and_return(payload)

test_target

expect(payload.my_text).to eq 'payload text'
```

Alternatively you could also use `expect_any_instance_of`, but I'd always prefer to use a specific double instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would mock `MyModule` to yield another mock, that would allow speccing that `my_text=` is called on the yielded object.

```
let(:payload) { instance_double('Payload') }

before do
  allow(MyModule).to receive(:send).and_yield(payload)
  allow(payload).to receive(:my_text=).and_return(nil)
end

# expectations 
expect(MyModule).to have_received(:send).once
expect(payload).to have_received(:my_text=).with('payload text').once
```

Comment: Thank you @spickermann for your answer! I used koffeinfrei's suggestion to solve the problem, but I'll still remember yours and use when needed.